# How do I displace a group of objects by a specified amount

Tags: displacement, groups

Id like to move an arrangement of spheres by a specified amount in all three dimensions.

Any clues how?

Thanks!

Comment: I would create an Empty and then parent all the spheres to that. You can the translate/animate the Empty and the Spheres will follow.

Comment: Did something like that, thanks!